# How to test activity start in another app using Robolectric

Tags: android, automated-tests, robolectric, android-testing

I have a scenario to test:

1. In my app, click a button - say, `btn1`.
2. `btn1` click uses an intent `action=VIEW`, `uri=http://www.m10v.com`, `category=DEFAULT` to launch another activity. This activity belongs to another package (e.g.: `browser`)
3. How do I:

   - Ensure that an application with an activity this intent filter is installed?
   - How do I test that the activity actually started?

Comment: I think this is out of concept of unit testing where Robolectric is used. I think checking that you form intent with properties correctly and launch is enough. Just as example - I wouldn't test that TV switch to special channel in test for remote control. I would just check that pressing the button generates correct signal

Answer (score 2):

Robolectric should be used for unit testing your code. It stubs out the android runtime, allowing for a fast test/refactor cycle. Tests run on the JVM and not on an emulator or device. Therefore you cannot use it for interacting with other components in the system.

For your scenario there are two options:

Write a unit test and only verify interactions, i.e. checking Intent attributes. You can use Robolectric or ActivityUnitTestCase for that.

Write a functional Ui test using the UiAutomator Framework (Api 16) or use the new UIAutomation Apis introduced with Api 18.